# Writing Part/Block of File to another File

Tags: vb.net

Please Help: I would like to read one block from file inPath and write to another file outPath.
I am using ReadLines method to read the File line by line and when reach at START_BLOCK, start writing to the output file and continue until you find the END_BLOCK.
I know couple of other methods by copying the whole file into a variable and pick the block what I need. I can't use saving on a variable as my files are very big GB+
The coding I have below copies the line at the "START_BLOCK" Can't really figure it out how to continue writing until the "END_BLOCK". Please suggest and thank you very much in advance.

```
    Dim inPath As String = "C:\temprm\myFile.txt"
    Dim outPath As String = "C:\temprm\myFileNew1.txt"
    Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(outPath)

        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(inPath)
            If line.Contains("START_BLOCK") Then
                sw.WriteLine(line)
                '-------HOW DO I CONTINUE TO WRITE UNTIL "END_BLOCK"
            End If
        Next line
    End Using
```

Comment: Would it be possible to include a few lines of your file into your question to get an idea of what they look like. Maybe include first 5 lines and then last 5 lines (not every single line will be needed).

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a flag to indicate that you are inside of the block, and use that to write out the lines until you find the end tag, e.g. something like this (untested code!):

```
Dim inPath As String = "C:\temprm\myFile.txt"
Dim outPath As String = "C:\temprm\myFileNew1.txt"
Dim insideBlock As Boolean = False
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(outPath)
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(inPath)
        If line.Contains("START_BLOCK") Then
            sw.WriteLine(line)
            insideBlock = True
        ElseIf line.Contains("END_BLOCK") Then
            sw.WriteLine(line)
            insideBlock = False
            Exit For
        ElseIf insideBlock Then
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        End If
    Next line
End Using
```

**UPDATE**

Since the comments are getting out of control - here's a version to handle multiple blocks with different start tags but the same end tag (untested since I'm at home on my Mac):

```
Dim inPath As String = "C:\temprm\myFile.txt"
Dim outPath As String = "C:\temprm\myFileNew1.txt"
Dim insideBlock As Boolean = False
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(outPath)
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(inPath)
        If IsStartOfBlock(line) Then
            sw.WriteLine(line)
            insideBlock = True
        ElseIf line.Contains("END_BLOCK") Then
            sw.WriteLine(line)
            insideBlock = False
        ElseIf insideBlock Then
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        End If
    Next line
End Using

'...

' Logic to determine if the line is the start of a block, for example:
Private Function IsStartOfBlock(line As String) As Boolean
    Dim startMarkers() As String = {
        "START_BLOCK", "START_BLOCK2", "START_BLOCKX"
    }
    Return startMarkers.Any(Function(x) line.Contains(x))
End Function
```

The loop will exit at the end of file anyway, so the last block should be ok too.

Comment: OMG!!! It works fine. This is what I was looking for. I can't Thank you Enough. Very much appreciated "MARK" Great Job.

Comment: @RDM Glad it helped, but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for better ways to say thanks. :-)

Comment: Mark: couple of issues with above codes, hope you could help me. (1) If "END_BLOCK" happens to appear before the "START_BLOCK", should be ignored. (what required is only to pickup block between "START_" and "END_". (2) "END_" in the actual program I am writing is an Empty Line, that's my end point where nothing on the line. I tried couple of things (i.e.) line.contains("") etc. but not working. Please help!

Comment: @RDM It sounds like you need to replace the first ElseIf line with `ElseIf insideBlock AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then`.  The check of `insideBlock` will ignore end lines before the start.  There is also `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` if your "empty" line actually contains spaces.  You could use `AndAlso line = ""`, but the `IsNullOrXXX` methods are a little more forgiving.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Its working as intended. I will thorough test more and update you tomorrow as well. Regards!

Comment: Mark.Works Great. Thank you. Could you please explain "insideBlock = False" under the first ElseIf. Kind of confusing for me. Regards!

Comment: @RDM That isn't really needed, since the `insideBlock` variable isn't used after that point, but at the time it just seemed better to reset it there since that was the end of the block, so you aren't inside it anymore. Maybe it's better to move the declaration of insideBlock inside the Using block to limit its scope and not worry about resetting it?

Comment: Understand better now. Moved insideBlock inside Using also. Thanks!

Comment: Mark, sorry to bother you again. But struggling with trying to pickup multiple Blocks from the file and leave marker in the file to be replaced later. I tried to make insideBlock1,2,3 etc.but not working form me. Not sure if this is the right direction....please help! thanks.

Comment: @RDM What about if you just remote the `Exit For` from the first `ElseIf` - that should get the loop to continue until the whole file has been read, and it should pick up the start of the next block (you will need the `insideBlock = False` statement in this case, so put that back if you removed it!), assuming that all blocks have the same start and end markers.

Comment: Actually blocks have different beginning in each case, and ending is the same except the last block which is end of file. Thanks

Comment: @RDM Assuming that your blocks are not nested, you can only be inside one block at a time, so in addition to my previous comment, you should be able to just expand the first `ElseIf` to add additional conditions - perhaps create an `IsStartOfBlock` method and put the conditions in there?

Comment: Yes the blocks are not nested. I will try as you have suggested. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Hello Mark, If I understood correctly, I expanded the ElseIf to add additional blocks. All of them has insideBlock=True except the one in the end of last block before the "Exit For" which is False. But its picking up each block and also all of the lines in between items as well. Also could you please guide me for the IsStartOfBlock method.  Please help! Thanks.

Comment: @RDM See update, but note that StackOverflow is not a chat forum or a personal help site - if you are going to keep changing the question, perhaps it's time for a new question?

Comment: Understood. Mark Thank you kindly.